# Representation of integers by positive definite ternary quadratic polynomials with linear terms

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms

There is a huge amount of research dealing with analysis of representation of integers by a quadratic polynomials only with terms of degree 2 (here is for example review of some known methods by J.Hanke: http://www.math.ubc.ca/~cass/siegel/hanke-ternary.pdf). There is a theory where we can expess corresponding theta series as a sum of Eisenstein series and cusp forms and then make some estimation on representation number as coefficients of theese series.

My question is the next: is it possible to extend these methods for analysis of representation of integers by quadratic quadratic polynomial with linear terms, especially when $n=3$ (for example, $m=5a^2+5b^2+5c^2+2a+2b+4c$)? My knowledge of theory of Modular Forms is not so good, so I would ask you an advice. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Completing the squares doesn't work?

Comment: The term "quadratic form" means a homogeneous quadratic polynomial, i.e. one without any linear and constant terms. Your question concerns quadratic polynomials, not quadratic forms.

Comment: Sorry, that's my lag in definition.

Comment: What are $n$, $m$, $a, b, c$?

Comment: $m$ is an integer that we want to represent, $a,b,c$ are unknown integer variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to extend these methods, although the picture is somewhat 
less clear than in the quadratic form case. When one discusses representations by a quadratic polynomial, this is equivalent to asking for representations by a *coset* of a lattice.

The theta series of a lattice coset is still a modular form, although usually for a smaller group than $\Gamma_{0}(N)$. This is described well in Iwaniec's book "Topics in Classical Automorphic Forms".

There is also a notion of genus for a lattice coset (see [this paper of Wai Kiu Chan and Byeong-Kweon Oh](https://arxiv.org/abs/1208.6060)), and this presumably says something about the Eisenstein series part of that theta series, although I don't think there's an analogue that's been worked out of the beautiful formula of Siegel that represents the Eisenstein series coefficient as a product of local densities. (At least, this is the impression I got from Wai Kiu Chan when I talked to him about it.)

Note that Chan has had a few students work on some problems about ternary quadratic polynomials (although not much from the modular forms perspective yet); in particular take a look at the work of Anna Haensch (see [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1402.1640) and [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.01654)) and [James Ricci](https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.00281).

In some cases, the problem really is as simple as completing the square. (Exercise: Prove that every non-negative integer can be written in the form $a^{2} + b^{2} + c^{2} + ab + ac + bc + a + b + c$.)

Comment: Jeremy, big thanks for your useful links! As for my example, completing the square does not work, because we have equation $5m+6=(5a+1)^2+(5b+1)^2+(5c+2)^2$, and elementary means do not clarify situation in that case, in contrary to, for example, the representation as sum of three triangular numbers.

Comment: Here's one more link. The [paper by Shigeaki Tsuyumine here](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jnt.2015.07.011) is about writing numbers as sums of three squares where congruences conditions are put on those squares. The main results of that paper imply that for sufficiently large $m$, there is a representation of $5m+6$ as $(5a+1)^2 + (5b+1)^2 + (5c+2)^2$.